# Display paragraph text instead of [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show, hidden

I am making an overlay to pop up when an image is clicked.  The overlay should have a picture and a paragraph in it.  It comes up, displays the picture, but does not display the paragraph that has been hidden from the actual page with the CSS "display: none;" feature and shown again with jQuery after the overlay comes up.  Instead, it displays "[object Object] where the paragraph should be.  I need it to show the actual text of the paragraph instead of simply registering that there is something there...

I have looked through the jQuery documentation and this seems to get me the closest to what I am looking for.  Before, I was getting nothing where the paragraph should be.  However, I have worked for 3 hours on this and I am stumped.  Does anyone have any advice?

HTML

```
<div class="INScarItem target">
  <a href="../INSnat.jpg">
    <img src="../INSnat.jpg" alt="Barrows carries Nationwide Insurance" />
  </a>
  <p class="testerTesty hide4target">
    This is a test!!! It has passed!
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#overlay img {
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin: 8% 20% 0;
}

#overlay p {
    color: #fff;
}

.hide4target {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p></p>");

//Add image
$overlay.append($image);

//Add overlay
$("body").append($overlay)

//Add caption
$overlay.append($caption);


//Capture the click event on a link to an image
$(".target a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var piclink = $(this).attr("href");
    var capText = $(this).children(":hidden").show();

    //Update overlay with the image linked
    $image.attr("src", piclink);

    //Update overlay with the caption text
    $caption.text(capText);

    //Show the overlay
    $overlay.show();

});

//When overlay is clicked 
$overlay.click(function(){
    //Hide the overlay
    $overlay.hide();

});
```

Comment: Are you setting the paragraph text with javascript from a json object maybe? Probably you are assigning the object instead a text or numeric property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In out case `$(this).children(":hidden")` you search in tag < a >, but < p > located in parent tag < div class="INScarItem target" >

Try this

```
var capText = $(this).siblings(":hidden").show();

$caption.text(capText.text());
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xehazu/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting text content of the paragraph, but complete jQuery collection (empty one, by the way, because `p` is not a child of `a`, but sibling), since `show` methods returns jQuery object. When you later try to use this collection setting it as a text content, object's `toString` method produces `[object Object]` string.

You can fix your code it like this:

```
var capText = $(this).parent().children(":hidden").text();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b31j9oj9/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting the local variable called `capText` to be a jQuery object.  When you set the text of the `$caption` element, you are setting it to be a jQuery object who's String representation is `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0):

Or here's another:

```
var capText = $(".target p").text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qhpfmdta/